# Make multiple api calls and hold data from each call in a variable as csv format

Tags: powershell, csv

So the following code produces a csv file with only the last row. I need all 5 rows (with the test file I'm using) to be populated and exported to a csv file.

```
$url = "https://example.com/api"
$data_type = "application/json"
$headers = @{
    "Content-Type" = $data_type
    "Accept" = "application/json"
}
$userId = ""
Import-CSV './userIds.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $userId = $_.id
    $body = @{
        Identity = $userId
        Site = "site_name"
        APIKey = "secret"
    }
    $body_json = $body | Convertto-JSON
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Body $body_json
}
$result | Export-Csv 'C:\scripts\powershell\output.csv' -NoType
```

I've tried `$list += $result`, but I just get a bunch of errors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I figured out the magic...

```
$url = "https://example.com/api"
$data_type = "application/json"
$headers = @{
    "Content-Type" = $data_type
    "Accept" = "application/json"
}
$userId = ""
$list = @()
Import-CSV './userIds.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $userId = $_.id
    $body = @{
        Identity = $userId
        Site = "site_name"
        APIKey = "secret"
    }
    $body_json = $body | Convertto-JSON
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Body $body_json
    $list += result
}
$list | Export-Csv 'C:\scripts\powershell\output.csv' -NoType
```

It doesn't make sense to me, because it's an array of tables... but if it works somehow merging the tables into one table... then I'm happy.